# Can you change the Vuetify Data Table "Rows Per Page" "All" value from the default "-1"?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

With the API I'm working with, using a page size of "-1" will show the default amount of items per page of 100, instead of the maximum amount of 10000.

I can change `items-per-page-options` from the default of `[5,10,15,-1]` to `[5,10,15,10000]`, but from what I can see, there's no option to change the label in the dropdown from `10000` to `All` because this is automatically done for `-1` by Vuetify.

Visual representation of my issue:

**Using the default `-1` for "All":**

[image: Default -1 value]

**Using the custom `10000` for "All":**

[image: Custom 10000 value]

Comment: Can you not just check the number when making an API request, eg `let itemsPerPage = page === -1 ? 10000 : page`

Comment: @Phil Yeah it looks like that may be the way to go. I was hoping for a more elegant solution on Vuetify's end I guess. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify doesn't seem to offer an option to customise the value that triggers the *"All"* label so you can simple handle this in your `update:page` / `update:options` event handler

```js
const itemsPerPage = options.itemsPerPage === -1 ? 10000 : options.itemsPerPage
```